# How to Export MongoDB Query Results to a File

Tags: javascript, mongodb, terminal, mongo-shell

I am running queries from mongo shell and get responses back on the screen.
I want to get the response and store it to a file(text or js for example).

For example: to store `db.persons.find({});` to a persons.js file on current path on the terminal `Users/david/my_files`

How can I do that?

Comment: What's wrong with cut and paste?

Comment: [see this](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/) , you can aggregate and store results in a collection, export that collection to bson, and convert it to a JSON file, maybe there is a faster way also

Comment: @Liam the response length is ~10,000 lines. I won't copy-paste it manually. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Can use `mongoexport`. See [here](https://database.guide/how-to-export-mongodb-query-results-to-a-json-file/).

In a nutshell:
`mongoexport --host=myhost.example.com --port=37017 --username=homer --authenticationDatabase=admin --db=my_db --collection=persons --query='{}' --out=data/persons.json`